# Does windows 2016 support Lotus Notes Client 8.5.3?

Tags: windows-server-2016, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I want to install Lotus Notes Client 8.5.3 on windows 2016. I am not sure whether 8.5.3 version is compatible with windows 2016. 
Does windows 2016 support Lotus Notes Client 8.5.3? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Notes 9 was introduced in 2013. So 8.5.3 was not even supported anymore at all when Windows 2016 came out 4 years ago.

So: No, Notes 8.5.3 is not supported on Windows 2016... it is not supported on ANY Platform anymore.... You might probably use a software version a little younger than 10 years...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Notes 9.  I believe the client 8.5.3 can be installed and run, but what will it be connecting to?  To read local databases, it should be OK, if the db's are also of the same version.